# Is jQuery currently using native query selector API?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering this question,

is jQuery currently using native query selector API?

from this benchmark: http://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-document-queryselector

the performance of native API is dramatically faster than jQuery library

will jQuery use the native API to increase query performance?

Comment: When it can, it does. Even when it does, native is still going to be ahead due to all the additional function calls.

Comment: thanks for explaination

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the latest codebases:

**1.11.1** https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.11.1/dist/jquery.js#L1200

**2.1.1**  https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2.1.1/dist/jquery.js#L1164

They both check for the support of querySelectorAll, and will use that. You will get similar speed than when using jquery and querySelectorAll in the case it exists (Some performance differences may exist because of the extra function calls). The good thing is that you're sure that it works in older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

This benchmark uses a very old version of jQuery, try benchmarking with the latest. It does use the document.querySelectorAll for speed but falls back to sizzle when it doesn't work since jQuery makes several extensions to the selector syntax.

Comment: I wouldn't consider jquery 1.11.1 very old. It's the latest version of the 1.1x branch which was launched on 5/1/14